# Accessing webpages in my virtualhost from another device

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache, wamp

my virtual host file is something like this..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\projects\web"
    ServerName mylocal
  <Directory "D:\projects\web">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

when i access it to my local i type something like this on my browser :

```
http://mylocal/login.html
```

and this works..

how ever when i tried to access

```
http://192.168.1.3(my ip address)/login.html
```

i got an not found error..

can you please guide me?.. im a newbie thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your system's IP address in the etc/hosts`(\Windows\system32\private\etc\hosts)` in your windows machine

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
##
#...
192.168.1.3         mylocal
```

Please restart the web server after this change

Comment: sir Saurabh :) thank for your reply!.. im trying to access it on my android device .. thanks! :)